# Can't run any mix command - ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in IO.chardata_to_string/1

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the exact same code and versions on my local mac and can run the mix commands fine. I pulled a completely fresh copy of my project to make sure. There is no _build, deps, or tmp directory. This error gives no information into the problem. What could be happening or what could I look into to solve this?

The problem is on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have tried multiple erlang/elixir versions and all result in the same output below.

```
root@instance-1:/srv/zipbooks/phoenix-api# elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.2.5] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [ds:2:2:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Elixir 1.8.1 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 21)
root@instance-1:/srv/zipbooks/phoenix-api# mix compile
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in IO.chardata_to_string/1    

    The following arguments were given to IO.chardata_to_string/1:

        # 1
        nil

    Attempted function clauses (showing 2 out of 2):

        def chardata_to_string(string) when is_binary(string)
        def chardata_to_string(list) when is_list(list)

    (elixir) lib/io.ex:461: IO.chardata_to_string/1
    (elixir) lib/path.ex:512: Path.join/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:888: :erl_eval.expr_list/6
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:240: :erl_eval.expr/5
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:232: :erl_eval.expr/5
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:233: :erl_eval.expr/5
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:888: :erl_eval.expr_list/6
```

Comment: did you just clone from git?  if so, maybe check what is in your gitignore and make sure you copied any files over that could have been missed

Comment: I did check that, nothing in gitignore that would be relied on

Comment: Does the error happen in both `dev` and `prod` environments on the server? I'm just guessing here, but I see a lot of `Path.join` calls in `mix/tasks/deps.compile.ex`. Perhaps you're including a dependency only in dev, or something else in your `mix.exs` that is misconfigured.

Comment: I tried all three environments, dev, prod, and test

Comment: Ok. Does `mix deps.compile` give you the same error?

Comment: yes, any mix command, including mix local.hex

Comment: ok turns out Path.join was being used in one of the config files based off an env variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be that a `nil` value is being passed to `IO.chardata_to_string`.  If you run `iex` and enter:

```
IO.chardata_to_string(nil)
```

you'll receive the same error.  Now, if you enter something like:

```
IO.chardata_to_string("my string")
```

you'll get the result you likely expect.

Without seeing your code, I can't say why you're getting the `nil` value that's being passed to IO.chardata_to_string, but that seems to be the issue.

I hope that helps.

Cheers!

Comment: As you can see from the stack trace, OP is not actually calling the function directly.

Comment: the problem ended up being a `Path.join` call in a config file